# jQuery Show and Scroll To

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a website where I hide all divs, until a user clicks on One, to show only that div.
This i am able to do, but now I whenever a div is being shown, I would like to scroll down to show it (not show the div when user scrolls, but scroll to the newly displayed div).

The good news is that all divs show up at the same point, aprox 600 pixels from the top. of th e page.

I need to make it scroll smoothly!! any help or comments will be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowPage(theid){ 
        var thearray= new Array("posexpress","comercio","contabilidad","produccion","marketing","reportes personalizados","reportes"); 
        for(i=0; i<thearray.length; i++){ 
        if(thearray[i] == theid){ 
            document.getElementById(theid).style.display="block";        
            var httpxml;
        } else { 
            document.getElementById(thearray[i]).style.display="none";
        }}}
    </script>
```

Comment: You usually get a ton better answers if you setup an example in over at http://jsfiddle.net   <<< Awesome site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. http://flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ It's a nice jQuery plugin that should do what you're looking for.

Comment: done deal. got it to work in seconds. only wished it had a smoother scroll. but will do for now! thanks